# iOS webm, ogg, ogv, mp4 playback in app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app where we use OGVKit pod at the moment in order to play/stream webm/ogg/ogv/mov videos (non-local). Now there's the new requirement to be able to play mp4 videos from an URL (non-local) and OGVKit kust supports local playback of mp4 files.

Is there a good library which supports playback of all these video file formats from non-local storage (stream) or do we need to switch between the AVPlayerVoewController/AVPlayerLayer?

I already tried to implement a switch which uses AVPlayerLayer if the file is not webm or ogg which partially worked but I couldn't get the layouting work correctly.

I also tried to search for an appropriate library but haven't found any yet.

Any ideas?